# How to update Sphinx Realtime Index with field = old_value + new_value?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, sphinxql

I am trying to `update the Sphinx Search Realtime Index` , using values from my Mysql Table.,
I want to `add the new value in the old value` of the RT index's record like this , 
i want to achieve this

```
UPDATE RT_index SET col1 = old_val + new_val WHERE id = xx ;
```

query i am trying is

```
UPDATE RT_index SET comments_count = comments_count + 3 WHERE id = 1157642
```

but Sphinx giving me errror

> ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT,
>   expecting CONST_INT (or 4 other tokens) near 'comments_count + 3 WHERE
>   id = 1157642'

i have tried query like this

```
 UPDATE RT_index SET comments_count = value(comments_count) + 3 WHERE id = 1157642;
```

but still sphinx gives error,

> ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT,
>   expecting CONST_INT (or 4 other tokens) near 'value(comments_count) +
>   3 WHERE id = 1157642'

How can i add new value in old value using update in sphinx real-time index ?

i am using PHP to do this.

there is not much info about it in http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Need to first run a SELECT query to get the current value, and then run the UPDATE.

Not sure if can use a transaction to make the update atomic.

Comment: yikes, thats more 1 query, per record. anyways thanks for your reply.